# func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) seems to never be called

Tags: swift, core-location

I have

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()  
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()  
locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
```

I also put everything in plist that starts with privacy location 
location services is turned on.

When I check

```
if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable()
```

it returns true but that method never seems to be called. Nothing happens.

Here's my full code. It's a mess right now from trying to test it.

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import CoreLocation

class GameViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

var locationManager:CLLocationManager!
var angle = 0.0
var rotate = SCNAction.rotate(by: 0.0, around: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), duration: 0.5)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()

    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/CompassObject2 copy.scn")

    let compassNode = scene?.rootNode.childNodes[0]
    compassNode?.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z: 0)

    let cameraNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:50, z:-5)

    let lightNode = SCNNode()
    lightNode.light = SCNLight()
    lightNode.light?.type = .omni
    lightNode.light?.intensity = 100000
    lightNode.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:150, z: 0)
    scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(lightNode)

    //let origin = SCNNode()
    //origin.position = SCNVector3(x:0, y:0, z: 0)
    let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: compassNode)
    lookAt.isGimbalLockEnabled = true
    cameraNode.constraints = [lookAt]

    _ = scene?.rootNode.childNode

    let scnView = self.view as! SCNView

    scnView.scene = scene
    scnView.allowsCameraControl = false
    scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    //print(compassNode?.position as Any)

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        print("yes")
    }
    else {
        print("no")
    }
    /*if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        print("yes")
    }
    else {
        print("no")
    }*/
    if angle != 0.0 {
        scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
    compassNode?.runAction(rotate)
}
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    //UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.angle = newHeading.trueHeading.toRadians
        self.rotate = SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(self.angle), around: SCNVector3(0, 1, 0), duration: 0.5)
    //}
}
/* func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    exit(0)
}*/
func locationManagerShouldDisplayHeadingCalibration(_ manager: CLLocationManager) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations newLocation: CLLocation) {
    print(newLocation)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    print("delegate works")
}
}

extension Double {
var toRadians: Double { return self * .pi / 180 }
}
```

It seems that the delegate does work because the func to check authorization status prints "delegate works" but the other funcs, most importantly didUpdateHeading still doesn't do anything as if it is never being called.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [didUpdateHeading not called in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35834700/didupdateheading-not-called-in-swift)

Comment: are you checking it on simulator ?

Comment: Please double check that you are properly setting the class(that encloses didUpdateHeading method) as the CLLocationManager delegate to get the callback.

Comment: @koen sorry that doesn't help.

Comment: @jawadAli yes however the simulator isn't capable of getting heading data so I'm downloading the app to my iphone and testing it that way

Comment: @NajeeburRehman as far as I know I am properly setting it as a delegate but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Try to get the current location to verify that the delegate method gets called or not. This is just for testing that delegate is properly set.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman Good idea. I created func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations newLocation: CLLocation) {
        print (newLocation)
    } and I ran it in the simulator and nothing got printed. Location services are turned on in the simulator.

Comment: 1) Set the delegate and call locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() method 2) Then check by printing any statement or breakpoint in locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {} method. This will verify that the delegate is properly set and the location access is provided or not.

Comment: If this will not help then share some more code of your class.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman alright I tried that and it successfully printed so I guess the delegate is correct. What should I do next?

Comment: Please add the complete code of your class and even the code how you are calling it.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman I added the full code to my question

Comment: What I have found is that heading is not available on simulator. You need real device for it . For me it is not even printing "heading available" message.
if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {
      print("Heading available..")
 }

Comment: @NajeeburRehman I am testing it on both my device and on simulator. I know that the simulator can't get heading data. if CLLocationManager.headingAvailable() {scnView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue} it changes the background in the app to blue on my device so I know that heading data is available.

Comment: Sounds good, its working for you.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman but func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) { still doesn't work. Nothing happens. It never gets called. How do I fix it?

Comment: Even in real device it is not working ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman I actually just found that locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {} doesn't work when run in the device when it did in the simulator.

Comment: didChangeAuthorization didn’t work in real device for you ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman Ok I found a way to make didChangeAuthorization work on my device. The problem was I had location services set to "always" so there was no change. By changing my location services to "while using the app" it changes when the app is run so that func is called. didUpdateHeading still doesn't work though and thats the main problem.

Comment: Is this `CLLocationManager.headingAvailable()` returning true on that device ?

Comment: @NajeeburRehman Yes it is.

Comment: Then try one thing may be it is the issue. In your viewDidLoad where your are creating an instance of CLLocationManager that is : let locationManager = CLLocationManager(). Remove the `let` keyword to store the reference in the variable you defined above name "locationManager" as you are not storing the location manager reference.

Comment: @NajeeburRehman That worked! Thank you so much for all the time you have spent helping me figure this out.

Comment: Glad to know it works for you. You are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have set the `CLLocationManager` delegate ?

On a side note, you do not need location permissions if you only want the user's heading.  If you want their actual location then you will need to request the appropriate authorisation and set the pList values.

```
import CoreLocation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self // <-- Make sure you have set this
        locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
        print(newHeading)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes my class is a CLLocationManagerDelegate and I have locationManager.delegate = self but it does not work